# How do I get my master public key from a wallet?

Tags: public-key, bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed, xpub

If a HD wallet only gives me the 12 word mnemonic, how can one get the master public key?

Comment: What wallet software are you using?  You've tagged this [tag:bitcoin-core] but AFAIK it doesn't use mnemonics.  Some wallet software will show you the master public key, though it might be buried in a menu somewhere.  You can also recover it from the mnemonic with third-party tools like [coinomi](https://coinomi.com/recovery-phrase-tool.html), though this requires you to trust that the software is not malicious (it could steal your coins if it were).

Comment: when you have your 12 words, and you are tech-savvy (the logic behind BIP32 or 39), then you can also try to download this website locally, and go from there: https://iancoleman.io/bip39/#english - but why would you want your master public key? Not the master priv key?

Comment: @pebwindkraft if you have the master public key, you can give it to a business for example to send payments spreaded out to different addresses, that's one use case. Thanks for the knowledge!

Comment: yup, I have seen your other posts, and now I know, there's more to it. A newbie user would ask for lost keys ... :-)

Comment: @pebwindkraft haha yeah you're right! Thanks again pebwindkraft!